# Для чего используется статический интерфейс?

Tags: java, android

В примере фрагмента определялся статический интерфейс для того, чтобы уведомлять активность о нажатиях:

```
static interface WorkoutListListener {
    void itemClicked(long id);
};
```

Почему интерфейс статический? К примеру, если переменная статическая — она используется в единственном экземпляре для всех экземпляров класса, но что делают статические интерфейсы?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Согласно JLS [8.5.1. Static Member Type Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.5.1):

> A member interface is implicitly static ([§9.1.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.1.1)). It is permitted for
>   the declaration of a member interface to redundantly specify the
>   static modifier.

---

> Интерфейс - член класса, неявно является статическим. При объявлении
>   интерфейса - члена класса допускается избыточное указание модификатора
>   `static`.

Конструкции

```
public class SomeClass {
    abstract static interface Interface {
        public abstract void foo();
    }
}
```

и

```
public class SomeClass {
    interface Interface {
        void foo();
    }
}
```

эквивалентны, т.к. интерфейс всегда `abstract`, вложенный интерфейс всегда `static`, а методы интерфейса [всегда](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4) `public`. До java 8 методы интерфейса всегда были `abstract`, в восьмой версии метод интерфеса может быть `static` или `default`, в отсутствие этих модификаторов `abstract` подразумевается. Явное указание модификаторов допустимо, но не приветствуется с точки зрения стиля.

Поля в интерфейсе [всегда](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3) `public`, `static` и `final`, избыточное указание этих модификаторов так же допустимо.

Comment: То есть `static` — в данном случае, значение не играет?

Comment: @bukashka101 он там в любом случае будет, но его можно вписать явно

Comment: Ну... В смысле просто лишнее слово, которое написано "просто так".

Comment: Кстати, нужно будет прочитать про нововведения в интерфейсы Java 8, на всякий случай. Спасибо :).